# Other than Lomb-Scargle Periodograms and String Length Minimization, what other methods can be used to find the period of unevenly spaced data?

Tags: observational-astronomy, asteroids, data-analysis, variable-star, cepheids

I'm doing some research into how different methods of finding the period with unevenly spaced data compare with each other. So far, I've looked at the Lomb-Scargle and String-Length Minimization. I was wondering if there are any other methods I've missed. Thanks!

Comment: I should add there may be others - I'm not saying my list of one is exhaustive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common method is to use the [autocorrelation function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/find-periodicity-using-autocorrelation.html) (ACF).

A description of an application of this technique for finding the rotation periods of stars in Kepler data is given by [McQuillan et al. (2013)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6787).